# PY4E- Finding Numbers in a Haystack

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on the assignment of a Python course in Coursera that involves using regular expressions.
It tells us to

> read through and parse a file with text and numbers. Extract all the numbers in the file and compute the sum of the numbers.

The data we use is [this](http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_330187.txt)

Here's my code:

```
import re
handle = open('regex_sum_330187.txt')
for line in handle :
    line = line.rstrip()
    numbers = re.findall('([0-9]+)',line)

print(sum(numbers))
```

It turns out that the sum is 0. So I'm a bit confused. If `re.findall()` is supposed to return a list of zero or more substrings, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just summing the last line. Why not move the summing inside the loop?

```
import re
handle = open('regex_sum_330187.txt')
numbers = 0
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    numbers = numbers + sum(map(lambda x: int(x), re.findall('([0-9]+)', line)))

print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
handle = open('regex_sum_330187.txt')
numbers = re.findall(r'[1-9]*',handle)
new_list = []
for i in numbers :
    if i :
        i = int(i)
        new_list.append(i)
print(sum(new_list))
```